AWS EKS TLS/SSL termination on NGINX ingress controller or on the ingress resource
Can someone tell me the difference between doing TLS termination in EKS in the NGINX ingress controller vs. the ingress resource. Not sure what the advantages are with either.
What happens if I have it on both? Which will be the primary?
